# C++: Is it obligatory to put a Strategy in a Wrapper to avoid bare new/deletes?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, wrapper, strategy-pattern

So I have discovered the joys of strategies.

```
class Strategy
{
public:
    virtual void action() = 0;
};

class FooStrategy : public Strategy
{
    virtual void action() { /* do some stuff */ };
};

class BarStrategy : public Strategy
{
    virtual void action() { /* do different stuff */ };
};

void computation()
{
    Strategy *strategy;
    if ( /* some decision logic */ )
        strategy = new FooStrategy();
    else
        strategy = new BarStrategy();

    //later on...
    //big loop! don't want any overheads beyond what if/else would give
    for (int i=0;i<100000000;++i)
    {
        //...various other code and then:
        strategy->action();
    }

    //...other code and possibly more strategy->action() calls, then finally:
    delete strategy;
}
```

All this is written to replace an `if/else` clause with the decision logic every time I need `action()`.  We can assume it reads more clearly because that's why we're using it.  As to overheads, the virtual function table for `strategy` will doubtless end up in the processor cache, so there should be little overhead compared to `if/else`, right?

However.  C++ doesn't allow abstract base classes on the stack, presumably as their size is unknown, so `strategy` has to live on the heap, introducing the dangerous `new` and `delete` operators.  Of course I could write a wrapper class to safely handle the creation and deletion of Strategies, and that would hopefully be optimized away entirely by the compiler.  But I wonder if, more elegantly, there is a way to put a `Strategy` on the stack, thus ensuring automatic deletion, given that all Strategies have the same size?

**Edit** Thanks for the replies everyone, I think they're all very good and enlightening as to different ways of doing things.  I'm going to abstain from accepting any individual one as correct.  I recommend any future readers to consider them all and be liberal with upvotes!

Comment: You'll need a virtual destructor to delete via a pointer to the base class.

Comment: Good point, should have one (even if it makes no difference with the code as above?  but you never know when someone might add something that requires it I guess)

Comment: It makes a difference even to the posted code; `delete strategy;` has undefined behaviour, since `strategy` points to a base class without a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a smart pointer?

```
std::auto_ptr<Strategy> strategy;
if ( /* some decision logic */ )
    strategy.reset(new FooStrategy());
else
    strategy.reset(new BarStrategy());
```

Now you have no need to `delete` anything.

C++11 offers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` as well. Also, Boost offers `shared_ptr` too, as well as `boost::scoped_ptr` (which is better than `auto_ptr` since copying an `auto_ptr` can cause issues. `scoped_ptr` is non-copyable).

Answer (score 1):

If you can decide that on call time, you could use templates:

```
template <typename TPolicyImpl>
void computation()
{
    TPolicyImpl policy;
 ...
}
```

and call it like:

```
  computation<FooPolicy>()
```

Comment: The decision is made at runtime.  Does that rule out templates?  (I have realised I am talking about strategy not policy - just edited, sorry).

Comment: can you put the if statement to the caller? like:   if ( /* some decision logic */ )
         computation<FooPolicy>()
    else
         computation<BarPolicy>();

Comment: I suppose this should have the nice characteristic of taking even less overhead than if-else, or a derived strategy class accessed through it's virtual function table :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go the smart pointer way, as suggested by others, or you can use the C-style way:

```
void fooStrategy() { /* do some stuff */ }

void barStrategy() { /* do other stuff */ }

void computation()
{
    typedef void (*Strategy)();
    Strategy strategy;
    if ( /* some decision logic */ )
        strategy = &fooStrategy;
    else
        strategy = &barStrategy;

    //later on...
    //big loop! don't want any overheads beyond what if/else would give
    for (int i=0;i<100000000;++i)
    {
        //...various other code and then:
        strategy();
    }

    //...other code and possibly more strategy() calls
}
```

**Edit**

Or, in the same line of thought. As long as your strategies are stateless, why not have a single global object for each strategy - then you wouldn't have to worry about deletion:

```
class FooStrategy : public Strategy
{
    virtual void action() { /* do some stuff */ };
} FooStrategyObject;

class BarStrategy : public Strategy
{
    virtual void action() { /* do different stuff */ };
} BarStrategyObject;

/* ... */

if ( /* some decision logic */ )
    strategy = &FooStrategyObject;
else
    strategy = &BarStrategyObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

- Make constructors for the 'Strategy' class and all other classes `private`
- Write a factory function that returns a smart pointer to a `Strategy` class with either reference counting or transfer of ownership semantics.  This should contain your `if` condition.
- Have each of your `Strategy` subclasses has this function as a `friend`.

This way, you will ensure that your `Strategy` objects are only created as parts of a smart pointer.  The disadvantage is that you will need to add the `friend` declaration to all current and future `Strategy` subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variant of the ScopeGuard pattern:

```
const Strategy& strategy = FooStrategy();
```

A const reference (and it has to be const) can be bound to a temporary, extending the lifetime of the temporary. This allows you to have everything safely (and efficiently) on the stack, while referring to the object by its base type (as a `const Strategy&`).

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how would you implement the OP's `if(/*some decission logic*/)` in this case? It probably needs to look like this instead: `const Strategy& strategy = StrategyFactory(/*decission input*/);` and move the decission to the factory method.

Comment: Either `const Strategy& strategy = (some condition)? FooStrategy() : BarStrategy();`, or simply `const Strategy& strategy = functionWhichCreatesTheCorrectStrategy();`

Comment: To my mind this would be the most elegant solution, but, how would you get `functionWhichCreatesTheCorrectStrategy()` to return the base class?  Seeing as you can't return an abstract base class except by pointer or reference, and that reintroduces the problem with deletion?

Comment: @SideshowBob: yeah, that's true, and that occurred to me yesterday after I posted this answer. You'd have to use the `?:` operator or something similar then (unless you can determine the strategy to use at compile-time, and then provide it as a template parameter)

Comment: Cool, glad I'm not missing something then.  Still good to know about const refs.

Comment: The `? :` method (used in a class initializer) gives error `Strategy: cannot instantiate abstract class` even though I'm trying to instantiate the concrete subclass :(